# how do I parse Any in dictionary using swift

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, any

I'm not how do it parse a dictionary value which is of type .
I'm able to read the key which is string and value is type of Any and has below sample `values` for given key

```
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 4 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : nativeName
      - value : Shqip
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : iso639_2
      - value : sqi
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : name
      - value : Albanian
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - key : iso639_1
      - value : sq
```

From above, I only need to extract "name":"Estonian"
Tired looping it did not work using swift.

Code:

```
    f(key == “languages”){
          var nameArray = value as! NSArray
                for str in nameArray{
                                     print(str)     
                                    }
}
```

Complete JSON response

```
[{"name":"Estonia","topLevelDomain":[".ee"],"alpha2Code":"EE","alpha3Code":"EST","callingCodes":["372"],"capital":"Tallinn","altSpellings":["EE","Eesti","Republic of Estonia","Eesti Vabariik"],"region":"Europe","subregion":"Northern Europe","population":1315944,"latlng":[59.0,26.0],"demonym":"Estonian","area":45227.0,"gini":36.0,"timezones":["UTC+02:00"],"borders":["LVA","RUS"],"nativeName":"Eesti","numericCode":"233","currencies":[{"code":"EUR","name":"Euro","symbol":"€"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"et","iso639_2":"est","name":"Estonian","nativeName":"eesti"}],"translations":{"de":"Estland","es":"Estonia","fr":"Estonie","ja":"エストニア","it":"Estonia","br":"Estônia","pt":"Estónia","nl":"Estland","hr":"Estonija","fa":"استونی"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/est.svg","regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"EU","name":"European Union","otherAcronyms":[],"otherNames":[]}],"cioc":"EST"}]
```

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: @AndreyChernukha - added code

Comment: Do not use Any. Do not use NSArray. Do not use NSDictionary. Is this JSON? You are parsing it incorrectly.

Comment: yeah it is json response. What to use instead of Any or NSArray ?

Comment: show the actual json and I’ll show you how to parse it and extract whatever you want

Comment: @Matt - added the complete JSON response.

Comment: I don't see "Albanian" anywhere in your JSON so the question how you can extract key "name" and value "Albanian" makes no sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187808/discussion-between-cybergeeeek-and-matt).

Comment: Let us not. Ask the question coherently and I'll answer it.

Comment: Also there is no key "airtime" in your JSON so that part makes no sense too. Please ask a question about actual values you want to extract from the actual JSON you have shown.

Comment: @matt - I hv updated my question with real value to be seached. Key is langauges and value I need is "Estonian"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use Any. Do not use NSArray. Do not use NSDictionary. This is Swift! Use Swift types and Swift decoding of the JSON.

Here is your JSON as a Data object:

```
[
    {
     "name":"Estonia",
     "topLevelDomain":[".ee"],
     "alpha2Code":"EE",
     "alpha3Code":"EST",
     "callingCodes":["372"],
     "capital":"Tallinn",
     "altSpellings":["EE","Eesti","Republic of Estonia","Eesti Vabariik"],
     "region":"Europe",
     "subregion":"Northern Europe",
     "population":1315944,
     "latlng":[59.0,26.0],
     "demonym":"Estonian",
     "area":45227.0,
     "gini":36.0,
     "timezones":["UTC+02:00"],
     "borders":["LVA","RUS"],
     "nativeName":"Eesti",
     "numericCode":"233",
     "currencies":[{"code":"EUR","name":"Euro","symbol":"€"}],
     "languages":[
         {
          "iso639_1":"et",
          "iso639_2":"est",
          "name":"Estonian",
          "nativeName":"eesti"
         }
     ],
     "translations":
      {
       "de":"Estland",
       "es":"Estonia",
       "fr":"Estonie",
       "ja":"エストニア",
       "it":"Estonia",
       "br":"Estônia",
       "pt":"Estónia",
       "nl":"Estland",
       "hr":"Estonija",
       "fa":"استونی"
     },
     "flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/est.svg",
     "regionalBlocs":[
       {
        "acronym":"EU",
        "name":"European Union",
        "otherAcronyms":[],
        "otherNames":[]
       }
     ],
     "cioc":"EST"
    }
]
"""
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Here is how to extract the language name from it:

```
struct Language : Decodable {
    let name : String
}
struct Entry : Decodable {
    let languages : [Language]
}
let entries = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Entry].self, from: data)
let lang = entries[0].languages[0].name // Estonian
```