# Access the inner info of a json in swift

Tags: json, swift

I retrieved my data but the data I need is in the first value which is "0", so how do I access something like the "price" or the "productname"

```
    ["0": {
        price = "4.77";
        productname = "KISSES Giant Milk Chocolate Candy, 7 oz";
    }]



URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
            print(json)


        } catch let jsonErr {

        }

    }.resume()
```

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504391/how-do-i-parse-any-in-dictionary-using-swift and many others. Stop using JSONSerialization. Use Decodable and just dive in and get the desired info.

Comment: @matt I tried but since the struct wont take a 0, it will give me an error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, don't use `JSONSerialization`, use `Decodable`.

There it's quite easy to *translate* the `"0"` into a legal struct member name with CodingKeys

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let zero: Product

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case zero = "0" }
}

struct Product: Decodable {
    let price, productname : String
}

...

let jsonString = """
{"0":{"price":"4.77","productname":"KISSES Giant Milk Chocolate Candy, 7 oz"}}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result.zero.productname)
} catch { print(error) }
```