# Parsing JSON response using Codable gives error in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to parse JSON response using Codable but it gives me error.
I tried to refer from the below stack overflow link but did not work.
[how do I parse Any in dictionary using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504391/how-do-i-parse-any-in-dictionary-using-swift)

Below is my code, not sure where I'm wrong in this.

```
> enum JSONError: String,Error {
>         case NoData = "ERROR: no data"
>         case ConversionFailed = "ERROR: conversion from JSON failed"
>     }

struct Owner : Decodable {
    let full_name : String
    let html_url:String
    let follower:follower
}

struct follower : Decodable {
    let followers_url : String
}


func jsonParser() {
        let urlPath = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:ruby&sort=stars&order=desc"
        guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath) else {
            print("Error creating endpoint")
            return
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:endpoint as URL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                guard let data = data else {
                    throw JSONError.NoData
                }

                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                    data)

                let entries = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Owner].self, from: jsonResponse as! Data)
                print(jsonResponse)
            } catch let error as JSONError {
                print(error.rawValue)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

I need to get 3 information from this response -  full name, html url and followers.
Link for web api

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:ruby

Please latest have a look at the code.

Below is the error message :

> '__NSDictionaryI' (0x102965a98) to 'NSData' (0x102964580). 2019-02-09
>   16:17:42.062971+0530 PhotoViewwer[13342:259997] Could not cast value
>   of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x102965a98) to 'NSData' (0x102964580).

Thanks

Comment: Which error you are facing?

Comment: @vadian - Error message - '__NSDictionaryI' (0x102965a98) to 'NSData' (0x102964580).
2019-02-09 16:17:42.062971+0530 PhotoViewwer[13342:259997] Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x102965a98) to 'NSData' (0x102964580).

Comment: There are many, many mistakes in the code, please see my answer. For example the `JSONSerialization` line is nonsense if you are going to use `Decodable`. This causes the error by the way.

Comment: @vadian - going via ur code so that I will come to know my mistakes. Thanks Vadian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please learn to read JSON. It's pretty easy. There are only two collection types, array (`[]`) and dictionary (`{}`)

Your structs are wrong.

In the root dictionary of the JSON there is an array of dictionaries for key `items`.
In each dictionary there are keys `full_name` and `owner` (**here** is the location of the `Owner` struct).
A dictionary for key `follower` does **not** exist.

These structs represent the JSON correctly

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    let items : [Item]
}

struct Item : Decodable {
    let fullName : String
    let owner : Owner
}

struct Owner : Decodable {
    let htmlUrl : URL // URL strings can be decoded directly into URL
    let followersUrl : URL
}
```

Add a completion handler to your function and use an enum as result type. The `failure` case returns all *real* errors. An `URLRequest` is redundant. Just pass the URL. The `JSONSerialization` line is pointless.

**The `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy converts *snake_cased* keys to *camelCased* struct members**

```
enum Result {
    case success(Response), failure(Error)
}

func jsonParser(completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
    let endpoint = URL(string:"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:ruby&sort=stars&order=desc")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let entries = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
            completion(.success(entries))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And call it

```
jsonParser { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let entries) : print(entries)
    case .failure(let error) : print(error)
    }
}
```

Basically never use `NS...` classes if there are native equivalents, here `URL` for `NSURL` and `URLRequest` for `NS(Mutable)URLRequest`

**Edit:**

In Swift 5 the syntax becomes more convenient using the native `Result` type. It is able to convert the throwing expression

```
enum Result {
    case success(Response), failure(Error)
}
```

```
func jsonParser(completion: @escaping (Result<Response,Error>) -> Void) {
    let endpoint = URL(string:"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:ruby&sort=stars&order=desc")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        completion(Result{ try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!) })

    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: above is working good but in one case it is failing.Incase full name is null it fails, how do I handle this case  - I want full name to be nil instead of failing while parsing the json.

Comment: Declare the struct member as optional: `let fullName : String?`

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
func jsonParser() {
    let urlPath = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:ruby&sort=stars&order=desc"
    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath) else {
        print("Error creating endpoint")
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:endpoint as URL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        do {

            let dec = JSONDecoder()
            dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let entries = try dec.decode(Root.self, from:data!)
            print(entries)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

---

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let items:[Item]
}
struct Owner: Codable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeId: String
    let avatarUrl: String
    let gravatarId: String
    let url, htmlUrl, followersUrl: String
    let followingUrl, gistsUrl, starredUrl: String
    let subscriptionsUrl, organizationsUrl, reposUrl: String
    let eventsUrl: String
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let fullName : String
    let htmlUrl:String
    let owner: Owner
}
```

You shouldn't cast the response to data here

```
from: jsonResponse as! Data)
```

as it will crash